# How to capture first td value (id) from table?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem, i tried take a  ID from  but don't work...
I tried with hidden field, id in  ID ...
You can help me? On site i commented where is the problem and where is the redirect file with ajax, but the problem don't is the ajax, is jquery, i think. This question is short, but i don't have no more to describe my problem... Don't work as expected, and i have no idea how make work...

**Code: http://liveweave.com/qrQ18A**

Comment: Is the `ID` in the first column?

Comment: From <td>, yes, is the first column, but i need check where is td (position), to access the ID

Comment: i hold my code, error stay in "parent" instead of "parents", tks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i have understood,you are looking for the position of the `<td>` with the class for ID.

```
$("tbody tr").each(function(){
     var b='';
     if($(this).find("td").hasClass("id"))
     {
         b=$(this).find("td").index();
         alert(b);       //THIS GIVES INDEX OF THE TD IN EACH TR.
     }
});
```

Comment: You can implement in my code (link in the question)
I echo var b, after?

Comment: @LuanDRGamer I dont know where exactly i need to add it in your code,but this code should help!

Comment: I tried and don't work, who i take the value from var b? I tried .val and .text, both return undefined, and i alert only var b, all return 0, i think 0 is the table position from ID td, correct, but i want value of this td

Comment: @LuanDRGamer Sorry for the late reply.Once you have got the `<td>`'sse index then just use, `$(this).find("td:eq("+index_var+")").html()`.

Answer (score 1):

### Change your code with the problem from this:

```
'id': $(this).parent('tr').children().first().text(), //HERE IS THE "PROBLEM"
```

### To this:

```
'id': $(this).parent().parent().children().first().text(), //HERE IS THE "SOLUTION"
```

You forgot to go up one more parent. I have to note that using $(this) and empty selectors for parent and children selectors can make your code harder to read.

I recommend that you use console.log() to show the object your trying to select. That way you might have seen your mistake. Good luck with it!

Answer (score 0):

try  `$('.id_th:first-child')`  instead of  `$(this)` to   specific target and see  if  it works

Comment: Don't work, i tried 'id': $(this).parent('tr').children().first().text(), and

'id': $('[target_class]:first-child').text(),

Comment: first tried $('[target_class]:first-child').parent('tr').children().first().text() and not $(this).parent('tr').children().first().text() has i told up.

Comment: I edited the code,  when i say [target]  class  i mean the name  of the  td class that you need.  i beleive it is  `id_th`